# Count JSON Requests from Api

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I am using an api which allows me 600 requests per hour.
My app is not finished so i test sometimes the JSON Requests. I guess about 10 requests per hour.

But the provider says I did 600.
How is that possible?
Is there a way to count the requests from my side?

I am doing the requests with my widget (Widgetkit). Is it possible that it does a realtime download request for every second?

My actual JSON Request:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    @Published var clubName = "..."
    @Published var teamId = "30"
    @Published var gastMannschaft = "..."
    
    let testStr = UserDefaults(suiteName: "gro")!.string(forKey: "test")
    

    
    init() {
            fetchData() // fetch data must be called at least once
        }

    func fetchData() {
        let teamId = testStr ?? "47"
        
        if let url = URL(string: "..." + teamId) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = gettingInfo {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                self.clubName = results.data[0].away_name
                                
                                
                                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                                    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
                                } else {
                                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                                }
                                
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check how much time is called `fetchData()`? How many times is called `NetworkManager()`? Could you print it to be sure? Like with `print("")`, and then, see your (multiples) logs and count? Or save it into a UserDefaults value (If you test on the same device/simul all the time)

Comment: Ok it is because if the new widget. I checked it now with deleting the widget. I will create a new topic with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a possibility that you are making some redundant requests which you might not be aware of.

To track your requests you could log them using for example [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com). This would reveal detailed information about requests you have made over the time you are performing them over the proxy.

Comment: Thank you that was the answer. It did 50 request just with one JSON Request. But how can I solve that problem? I don't know where I did somethings wrong. I am gonna update the first post with my JSON Request.

Comment: It was because of the widget. Checked it now.

Comment: See your configuration for the widget's `TimelineProvider` and adjust it to your needs

Comment: What exactly do I have to change? If you add a widget there is a sample code which confuses me. Do you have a link?